# Add class to div above

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, addition

I have the following html structure:

```
<div> ... </div>
<div> ... </div>
<div> ... </div>
```

And what I'm trying to do is whenever I add the class **active** to a div tag the div tag immediately above it will get the class **inactive**. Could something like this be possible to achieve using JQuery?

**UPDATE**

I tried the following but this adds a class to the parent DIV and not to the DIV above it:

```
if ($('div').hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).parent().addClass('inactive');
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where is the `div`s in HTML? And also add your jQuery code.

Comment: There is no effort here. The task you're asking for is simple. Go do a jQuery tutorial and you'll learn it in about an hour.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Show us what you've got so far!

Comment: I made a mistake. Instead of <SELECT> I meant <DIV>... I updated my question

Comment: @TiagoSousa Answering your question, Yes you can do that by using jQuery, look at the functions addClass() and removeClass()

Comment: I tried some JQuery but it adds a class to the parent div and not to the div above it

Comment: change `.parent()` to `.prev()` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery `parent()` function returns the parent element of the selected element. See https://api.jquery.com/parent/

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

You should use the `prev()` function to find the previous element in your DOM.
Take a look at the documentation page: https://api.jquery.com/prev/

Your code could look like this:

```
var $current = $('div.active');
var $previous = $current.prev();

$previous.addClass('inactive');
```

The `$` before the variable name indicates that it contains a DOM element.

**Fiddle**

https://fiddle.jshell.net/30tf4ytw/7/

Comment: Mmm it doesn't work... https://fiddle.jshell.net/30tf4ytw/2/ Am I doing something wrong here? Thanks